# Remove user's access to .config and Library folders

Tags: macos, finder, permission, sudo, library

I used the following commands to give myself access to the .config folder in order to access Google Chrome's internal files.

```
sudo chown user ~user/.config
chmod 711 ~user/.config
```

That did not give me access to the .config folder, but it gave me access to the Library folder.  I am not sure what the relationship between those two folders is, but that's where the Chrome files ended up being located.

Having access to the Library folder is now interfering with my work, because lots of unneeded files are turning up in Finder searches now, and I would like to reverse those commands.

My username on MacOS is user (I realize it's probably not the best practice), and that account is also the machine's admin.  How do I reverse both ownership and chmod modifications made earlier?

Comment: macOS has multiple Library folders, so you need to be clear about which you mean. I'm really not sure what it is that you're trying to achieve. You seem to have come up with a possible fix & are asking about that. It's far better to ask about you *actual* problem, not what you thing you need to do to fix it. This is known as an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: I am talking about the user/Library folder.  I thought I had described the actual problem with high precision.  Unneeded files (hundreds of thousands of them) started turning up in Finder searches that didn't before.  Before I ran the command above, those files were not accessible, now they are.

Comment: @Dave Neither one of those commands affects ~/Library.  You already have access to ~/Library without doing anything.

Comment: @MarcWilson is it normal to be able to find files contained in Library by searching, but not being able to see that folder in home?

Comment: @Dave Certainly.  The ~/Library folder is hidden by default, that doesn't stop Spotlight from indexing it.

Comment: There's no global chmod setting for contents of ~/Library. ~/Library/.config is 744, but many others are 700. You already own everything in there afaik, so that isn't what broke; & because of the location, I'm not really sure there's any practical difference between 711, 700 & 744.